# OpenAM OAuth token issue not invalidate when multiple SSO servers

Tags: openam, forgerock

I have set up two servers (sso1,sso2) for SSO using server setting in OpenAM UI >>deployment >> servers. When I hit request like

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://locahost:8080/sso1/oauth2/test1/token/revoke' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=<<token>>' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=XXXX' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=XXXX'
```

It gives success. Now in order to validate whether the token is revoked or not, I have used the following API

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/sso1/oauth2/tokeninfo?access_token=<<token>>&realm=/test1'
```

So the above method looks fine it gives an error like invalid_token. But when I check the same token with sso2 it gives a valid response. So my question is how can I revoke a token that invalidates from all server pools which configures at the SSO level?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 tokens are stored in CTS persistence store. You need to check that CTS persistence store infrastructure works as expected (e.g. if it's replicated)

Comment: Where should I check? I have used Default Token Store in CTS

Comment: You must never use 'Default Token Store in CTS' as this means it's using OpenAM's SMS API instead of straight LDAP.

If you use 'Default Token Store' it means the tokens are persisted in OpenAM configuration data store.

Comment: But there is a blacklist token polling interval too in the configuration which fetches from other servers configured in SOO. isn't it work for Default Token Store?

Comment: 'Default Token Store' only means a different OpenAM API is used which has less features from LDAP access point of view.

Comment: To note, you can not use an LB for CTS persistence store, no matter which mode is used. This is related to the replication and consistency model of OpenDJ